# How to change PrimeNG p-fieldset layout

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a page using fieldset and input like :

```
<mat-card >
  <mat-card-title></mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content >
    <form>
     <p-fieldset legend="Recruiter Info">
        <mat-grid-list cols="3" gutterSize="5px">
            <mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input #recruiter name="recruiter" matInput placeholder="Recruiter">
                    <mat-error></mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input #recruiterIdCard name="recruiterIdCard" matInput placeholder="ID Card No.">
                    <mat-error></mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </mat-grid-tile>
          </mat-grid-list>
      </p-fieldset>
    </form>
```

but when page loads, the layout is so large. I try to change it by adding the style to fieldset but it has not effect.
[image]
please advice me.

Comment: Be careful using tags : all of them were wrong.

Comment: @Antikhippe: Could you explain more details?

Comment: primes != primeng - primeng works with angular, not angularjs - angular is related to javascript, not typescript. Finally, this is more a question about CSS than typescript.